# Trying to print text from WebElements to the same line when that text was gathered using for loops?

Tags: python, selenium

Individually the `prints` in my for loops correctly print the items I want, but I'm having difficulties printing them together on the same line.

```py
#Grabbing text from the first column in the table that contains "Elephant"

for cell in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Elephant')]"):
    ElepantText = cell.text
    print(ElephantText)

#This prints:
#Elephant 1
#Elephant 2
#Elephant 3 etc...which is what I want

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[contains(text(),'Elephant')]/following::td[1]/span/select[1]"):
    selected = Select(element).first_selected_option
    select_text = selected.text
    print(select_text)


#This acquires the selected option in the dropdown menu following the cell that contains "Elephant" and prints the selected option which is what I want.
```

I tried:

```py
print(ElephantText, select_text)
```

But this just returns the last value in ElephantText and none of the select_text Selected options.

I also tried to zip the two together using:

```py
zipped = zip(ElephantText, select_text)
print(zipped)
```

But it returns this:

```
<zip object at 'random hexadecimal number'>
```

I tried turning these into lists again, but it just turned each letter in the result into an item within the list, so I'm kind of out of ideas at this point. Any direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is what I'd like my results to look like:

Elephant 1 - Selected

Elephant 2 - Selected

Elephant 3 - Selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElephantText and selected_text are strings. You cannot zip them. You need to store all the text values (if you're iterating over the collections one after the other) and then zip the list of text values:

```
ElephantTexts = []

for cell in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Elephant')]"):
    ElephantText = cell.text
    print(ElephantText)
    ElephantTexts.append(EelephantText)


Selected_texts = []

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[contains(text(),'Elephant')]/following::td[1]/span/select[1]"):
    selected = Select(element).first_selected_option
    select_text = selected.text
    print(select_text)
    Selected_texts.append(selected_text)

merged = tuple(zip(ElephantTexts, Selected_texts))    # assuming they are the same size
for tup in merged:
    print(tup)
```

I ran the following code with hardcoded lists:

```
ElephantTexts = ['Elephant1', 'Elephant2', 'Elephant3']
Selected_texts = ['Selected1', 'Selected2', 'Selected3']
merged = tuple(zip(ElephantTexts, Selected_texts))    # assuming they are the same size
for tup in merged:
    print(tup)
```

and this is the output:

```
('Elephant1', 'Selected1')
('Elephant2', 'Selected2')
('Elephant3', 'Selected3')
```

Comment: So this was able to combine them into a list, but the list is divided into two parts. ```(['Elephant 1',' Elephant 2', 'Elephant 3;'], ['Selected', 'Selected, 'Selected'],)```. I need them to be printed out on the same line like: Elephant 1 - Selected, Elephant 2 - Selected, etc. I'll edit my original comment to better reflect it.

Comment: I think I had an extra parenthesis in there that might cause an issue. Just fixed it and I am able to print exactly what you want. See my edits.

Comment: That almost did it, any idea why it wouldn't print the second 'Selected'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the second 'Selected'? I'll edit the code to make it a little clearer what's happening

Comment: So I didn't realize ```Selected_texts``` also included ```''``` between each of the 'Selected' items I needed. Was able to remove those and now it is printing what I need. Thank you!